# How to use filenames having special characters with awk '{system("stat " $0)}'

Tags: awk, escaping, system

For example, list.txt is like this:

```
abc.txt
-abc.txt
```

I couldn't get the correct answer with either
`awk '{system("stat " $0)}' list.txt` or `awk '{system("stat \"" $0 "\"")}' list.txt`.

How could I tell the awk-system to add quotes around the filename?

`awk '{system("stat " $0)}' list.txt` certainly would not work.
But why `awk '{system("stat \"" $0 "\"")}' list.txt` wouldn't either? It behaves just like the former.
But with `awk '{system("stat \\\"" $0 "\\\"")}' list.txt`, I would got this:

```
stat: cannot stat '"abc.txt"': No such file or directory
```

Comment: `awk '{system("stat \"" $0 "\"")}'` works for me in both bash and csh. What shell are you using?

Comment: Unless you sanitise `$0`, your code is vulnerable to [injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) attacks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want to get the output of the `stat` command, `system()` is not the right way to go. It merely returns the return code instead of the execution output.

You may try `cmd | getline myOutput` in awk. The `myOutput` variable will hold the output (one line only). Or, you can write on a pipe `print ... | cmd` to print the output

Regarding your file `-abc.txt`. Quoting it isn't enough. You can try to execute it in terminal `stat "-abc.txt"` it won't work, as the filename starts with `-`. You need to add `--`: `stat -- "-abc.txt"` So, you probably want to check if the filename starts with `-` and add the `--` in your awk code.

Finally, about quote, you can declare an awk variable, like `awk -v q='"' '{....`  then, when you want to use `"`, you use `q`, in this way, your code may easier to read. E.g., `print "stat " q "myName" q`